# best way to backup data to a sftp server

Tags: backup, sftp, lftp

In my projects, I have work on a 800 GB of data (that includes data and codes). Some part of my data is constituted by somewhat large files, ~1GB, but I have also some folder with thousands of small files inside.

I have backed up all my data on a external server with `sftp`, and I have used `lftp`, using `mirror -R <folder>`. I have found out that this way of backing up the data may not be ideal, because `sftp` works better with large files and it takes long time to back up small files.

Now that I have copied all my data on the external server, I would like to incrementally save the changes everyday, given that I work constantly on my projects and I update several distinct folders at a time.

I was used to do backup with `rsync`, but I believe this is not an option on the external server I am currently using.

I was wondering if there is some way I can speed up this process using `sftp`, either within `lftp` or another file manager.

Comment: Do you require a directly accessible backup (individual files), or would you use a dedicated backup tool that stores compressed archives?

Comment: Why can't you use rsync?

Comment: @grawity I would like if you can elaborate on the compressed archives, because I am not sure what you mean. In principle it would be more convenient for me to access the data file by file

Comment: @harrymc I guess it is not installed. This server is managed by a third part, I know they have run sftp protocol

Comment: @simona: I was going to suggest backup software such as Restic, which stores data in a proprietary format, but deals rather well with incremental backup.

Comment: If you can't install software, then what kind of help are you asking from us?

Comment: I can install software locally in the place where I have the data, not on the receiving server